# Memory table-size

Tags: c++, memory, x86

I have files, describing structure of 32 bit virtual address space of process. For example:

- 08048000-08053000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 18877      /usr/bin/cat
- 08053000-08054000 r--p 0000a000 08:03 18877      /usr/bin/cat
- 08054000-08055000 rw-p 0000b000 08:03 18877      /usr/bin/cat
- 091e3000-09204000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
- 4f2d0000-4f2ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1857       /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
- 4f2ef000-4f2f0000 r--p 0001e000 08:03 1857       /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
- 4f2f0000-4f2f1000 rw-p 0001f000 08:03 1857       /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
- 4f2f7000-4f4a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
- 4f4a2000-4f4a3000 ---p 001ab000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
- 4f4a3000-4f4a5000 r--p 001ab000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
- 4f4a5000-4f4a6000 rw-p 001ad000 08:03 1858       /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
- 4f4a6000-4f4a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
- b75c0000-b77c0000 r--p 00000000 08:03 57661      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
- b77c0000-b77c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
- b77d9000-b77da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
- b77da000-b77db000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
- bf819000-bf83a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]

There is a two-level virtual memory on x86 processors. Size of one page is 4096 bytes. One page directory contains 1024 records, having 4 bytes sized each.

How can I count overall size of virtual memory tables?

Comment: Have you tried doing this calculation yorself?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I want to do it, but I don't understand how to do it. I thought I can count nonzero offsets(3 column in table) and multiply by 4096, and so I get size in bytes. But I am not sure, if it is right way. Can you explain me, how I can do it?

Comment: So, my question was basically "try to do the calculation and explain what you have done" - it's not exactly rocket science, it's pretty basic calculations.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I explain you, that I don't fully understand, that I am doing it right. I described you the method, I use, and want to know it's correct. Can you answer me, if it is correct, or explain if it's not.

Comment: Multiplying the size in the above table by 4096 is clearly NOT right.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Can you explain me how it works, I mean memory tables, or give me link to article, where it's explained? Because now, i don't understand how to calculate overall size of virtual memory tables.

Comment: There is one root node, that points to 1024 nodes that each point to 1024 nodes pointing to memory. So 1+1024+1024*1024=x??? (multiply by 4 to get size in bytes).

Comment: @Surt It is for overall table, independently from file. But I need to count size for certain file, and it is not constant 1 + 1024 + 1024*1024.

Comment: how did you find these values? they are in hex so either grab them while still in integer or convert them to integer from text.

Comment: @Surt about which values are you talking about? So if I have 7 nonzero values in third column, I have to sum: 1 (one root node) + 7(7 nonzero nodes) + 7*1024 and then multiply this sum by 4 and this way I get size?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Can you answer my comments under your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is ONE page-table entry (PTE) for every 4096 bytes. And one page directory entry for each 1024 PTEs.

So the number of entries of each would be:

```
ptes = (x + 4095) / 4096;
pdes = (ptes + 1023) / 1024
```

The +4095 and + 1023 is to "make sure we have at least one for any non-zero value", and the above assumes integer values for `x` and `ptes`.

I'll leave it to you to add the two numbers together and multiply up to give you bytes.

Of course, if you want to be efficient, use `>> 12` instead of `/ 4096` and `>> 10` instead of `/ 1024` - this will guarantee that the compiler doesn't actually perform a divide operation.

When we have multiple memory ranges, you need to one PDE for each "big lump" (1024 x 4096 bytes, so even 4MB ranges will have a PDE), then one PTE for even 4K region.

So from your example:
    08048000-08053000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 18877 /usr/bin/cat
No memory. Reserved.

```
08053000-08054000 r--p 0000a000 08:03 18877 /usr/bin/cat
```

1 PDE, 10 PTE (0xa000 = 10 * 4096 bytes)

```
08054000-08055000 rw-p 0000b000 08:03 18877 /usr/bin/cat
```

0 PDE, 1 PTE  (0xb000 - 0xa000 = 0x1000 = 4096 bytes)

```
091e3000-09204000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [heap]
```

No memory, reserved.
    4f2d0000-4f2ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1857 /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
No memory, reserved

```
4f2ef000-4f2f0000 r--p 0001e000 08:03 1857 /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
```

1 PDE, 1 PTE  (0xf0000 - 0xef000 = 4096 bytes)

```
4f2f0000-4f2f1000 rw-p 0001f000 08:03 1857 /usr/lib/ld-2.15.so
```

0 PDE, 1 PTE

```
4f2f7000-4f4a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1858 /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
```

No memory, reserved range

```
4f4a2000-4f4a3000 ---p 001ab000 08:03 1858 /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
```

0 PDE, 1 PTE

```
4f4a3000-4f4a5000 r--p 001ab000 08:03 1858 /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
```

0 PDE, 2 PTE (0xa5000 - 0xa3000 = 2000)

```
4f4a5000-4f4a6000 rw-p 001ad000 08:03 1858 /usr/lib/libc-2.15.so
```

0 PDE, 1 PTE

```
4f4a6000-4f4a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75c0000-b77c0000 r--p 00000000 08:03 57661 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b77c0000-b77c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b77d9000-b77da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b77da000-b77db000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]
bf819000-bf83a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]
```

So, I would argue that in total, this particular executable has 2 PDEs entries and 18 PTEs. I may have counted something wrong, but in principle that's how you'd do it for this particular example (which appears to be part-way through loading, as it's not using any stack or heap, which is unlikely for a fully running program - this may be that the statistic was gathered before the program actually got running fully, or some such)

Comment: I can calculate size of mapped virtual memory of process. For table above, it is 4345856 bytes, so number of ptes = 1061. So pdes = 2. And then I have to do what?

Comment: I cant understand, why size of table in my example is 28672. I do next calculations: 4345856 - size of mapped virtual memory of table, so 4345856/4096 = 1061 pages, 1061 / 1024 = 2 page dirs of second level, so 2 dirs and one that link to them, so 3 * 1024 * 4 = 12288. I added full table in question.

Comment: So for that example, you need (1061 + 2) * 4 bytes. Can't be bothered to get out the calculator.

Comment: However, see my edit as to calculation of page-table size. I don't know where 28672 comes from.